# Hibernate JPA 2.0 update only and insert in child tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am new to Hibernate JPA.....I have one parent table and multiple child tables.I want to insert the record in child tables basing on parent table existence.I do not want to insert any record in parent table.If entry exist in parent table then i want to insert in child table. I tried with insertable and updatable in parent table primary key as false. but it is not working. I am using JPA 2.0 version.Thank you in advance. Please let me know for any other information.

================ Copy-pasted from comments:

Code Sample :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Custome.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Customer p") 
public class Customer extends AbstractObject implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private CustomerPK pk;

 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Column(name="end_dt") 
 private Date endDt; 

 @Column(name="desc_txt") 
 private String descTxt; 

 //bi-directional many-to-one association to Dependent 
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
 private List<Dependent> dependents = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

I want to update descTxt in customer table and wan to insert Dependent table . If CustomerPK exist in table then i want to update if not i want to skip updating of record in Customer table and insertion also. currently i am using session.saveorUpdate(object) If record exist it is updating parent record and inserting in child table , But if parent record does not exist then it is inserting parent record and child records which i didn’t want to insert in parent record

Comment: Please add some code to show what you are trying to do? What are the parent and child entities, and how are they related?

Comment: Code Sample :@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Custome.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Customer p")
publi } c class Customer extends AbstractObject implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @EmbeddedId
 private CustomerPK pk;

 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Column(name="end_dt")
 private Date endDt;

 @Column(name="desc_txt")
 private String descTxt;

 //bi-directional many-to-one association to Dependent
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Dependent> dependents = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I want to update descTxt in customer table and wan to insert Dependent table .
If CustomerPK exist in table then i want to update  if not i want to skip
updating  of record in Customer table and insertion also.
currently i am using session.saveorUpdate(object)
If record exist it is updating parent record and inserting in child  table , 
But if parent record does not exist then it is inserting parent record and child records  which i didn’t want to insert in parent record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA will not fix this. If you call 'saveOrUpdate', it will save or update. It would be very bad if it where to behave like you expect.

In practice, you should never create a new Customer object if you do not intend to save it. You best implement your check in code outside of JPA, e.g.

```
Customer customer = entityManager.find(Customer.class, customerPK);
if(customer != null){
  customer.setDescription(...)
  customer.addDependent(new Dependent (...))
  //customer + dependents will be saved at end of transaction or at flush
}
else {
  LOG.info("Ignoring unexisting id", customerPk)
}
```

Note:

- There's no need to call session.saveOrUpdate if the customer instance was created by Hibernate, and you do proper transaction/session mgmt. Hibernate will track all changes to persistent objects in the current session and flush them at the end of the session.
- If you add a Dependent to the customer's dependents list (best practice is to use an addXxx method), it will automatically be inserted with the correct foreign key at the end of the session as well.

Comment: Thank you for the update.. it will try and let you know  this option .

Comment: Thank you for the update.. it will try and let you know ...One more clarification i am looking for  is  customer.addDependent(...) need to be added in Customer ? or else can i use session.saveorupdate after checking the existence of Customer entity?

Comment: See added notes